# Is there any evidence that humans have faced extinction before?

Tags: human-genetics, extinction

Have we as a species faced extinction in the past? Resulting in a 'population bottleneck'?  If so, what genetic evidence is there of this occurring?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is ample genetic evidence for a [population bottleneck following the out-of-Africa migration](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12433581). This would account for the reduced genetic diversity found in non-African populations.

There is further evidence for an [earlier major bottleneck](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v475/n7357/full/nature10231.html) that reduced the human population to around 10,000 individuals.

These kinds of studies are typically done now via [Coalescent theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coalescent_theory) using whole-genome sequences.

---

I just found this nice [blog post](https://whyevolutionistrue.wordpress.com/2011/09/18/how-big-was-the-human-population-bottleneck-not-anything-close-to-2/) summarizing the Nature paper I linked to.

Comment: Excellent information! I am also intrigued as to what caused these bottlenecks.  I used to follow the notion that an eruption of the supervolcano Toba, Indonesia caused an almost extinction bottleneck - but it seems that this is not the case anymore.